# Add coloured circle inside the text of an input element label (in Shiny)

Tags: html, shiny

I have a checkBox input element in Shiny Dashboard.

How to add a geometric shape (such as a circle) inside a label of an input element (e.g. a checkBox). I would also like to be able to modify the size and the colour of the circle independently of the font size of the text that goes before or after the circle.

Comment: Should this shape overlay the label or should it be placed next to it - like an icon?

Comment: Like an icon, actually even as an ASCII symbol, just to have it with different colour and font size.

Comment: I left an example below.

Answer (score 0):

This might get you started:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$style(HTML(".icon-style {color:#E87722;}")),
  checkboxInput("test", label = span("Test", icon("circle", class = "icon-style")), value = TRUE),
  checkboxInput("test", label = span("Test", icon("circle", class = "icon-style fa-3x")), value = TRUE)
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Also see [this](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.0.1/icon.html) related article.